# Primes $(a,b,c)$ such that $a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc=28$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, conic-sections

This problem was the first version of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4800988/what-numbers-smaller-than-28-can-be-values-of-the-expression-e-a2b2c2-ab/4807504#4807504) which was simplified by the O.P. to its actual version.

**For what prime values of (a,b,c) the expression $f(a,b,c)=a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc$ is equal to 28?.**

I wonder there are infinitely many solutions. Here my approach.

For $a$ fixed we have an ellipse whose semi-axes measure, $\sqrt{56}$ the largest (located at the diagonal) $y=x$, and $\sqrt{\dfrac{56}{3}}$ the smallest. When $a$ changes the ellipse simply moves along the diagonal $y=x$.

In the attached figure it is shown first the original ellipse (in red) and its normal form (in black) when $a=11$ and second, two ellipses in the original form for the values $a=11$ and $a=23$ (in this second figure the scala has been changed in order to have the figure well set up)
[image]

[image]

We take as examples of the approximation to the method we want to apply, two ellipses corresponding to the values $a=17,19$ (we already know that the two ellipses have the same size;look at the figure below).

For $a=17$ (red in the figure ) one has the six integer solutions $(a,b,c)=\boxed{(17,23,11)},(17,15,11),\boxed{(17,13,19)},(17,21,15),\boxed{(17,23,19)},(17,21,23)$ (there are more all just changing $(b,c)$ by $(c,b))$ where **three** of them are prime so solutions of the problem.

For $a=19$ (green in the figure) we have the six integer solutions $(a,b,c)=(19,15,13),\boxed{(19,17,13)},(19,21,15),\boxed{(19,23,17)},(19,25,21),(19,25,23)$  (there are more all just changing $(b,c)$ by $(c,b))$ where **two** of them are prime so solutions of the problem.
[image]

The idea for a possible proof is to apply Dirichlet's theorem of the arithmetical progression because we know  that for distinct values of $a$ (always take with prime values), the ellipse is the same, only moving, as above said, along the diagonal $y=x$.

Comment: There's [an open problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_triplet#Conjecture_on_prime_triplets) lurking here.

Comment: @J.G. : Thanks. Yes I know something about it. Precisely I have taken twin numbers. as examples. I believe that Dirichlet's theorem works for end this problem (this of this post, not the triplet) because there are  A.P. in place. In the given examples with $17$ and $19$ the solutions differ in $2$ (Sorry for bad English).

Comment: Let $a<b<c$. For $c<1000$ is `30` solutions and for $c<10000$ is `112` solutions?

Answer (score 1):

$a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc=28$

$a(a-b)+b(b-c)+c(c-a)=28$

$a(a-c)+b(b-a)+c(c-b)=28$

$(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(a-c)^2=56$

$x^2+y^2+z^2=56$

$x+y=z$

$x^2+y^2+(x+y)^2=56$

$x^2+y^2<56$

$x,y\in \mathbb N, x^2+y^2<56\implies x^2+y^2 \in \{1,2,4,5,8,9,10,13,16,17,18,20,25,26,29,32,34,36,37,40,41,45,49,50,52,53 \}$

$56=1+55=4+52=9+47=16+40=25+31=36+20=49+7$

$z^2\in \{4,16,36,\}\implies z \in \{\pm2,\pm4,\pm6\}$

$x^2+y^2=52=6^2+4^2+2^2\implies x=6, y=-4, z=2$

$x^2+y^2=40=6^2+2^2+4^2 \implies x=6,y=-2, z=4$

$x^2+y^2=20=4^2+2^2+6^2\implies x=4,y=2,z=6$

---

$a-b=4. b-c=2. a-c=6$

$a=b+4$

$c=b-2$

---

$b=7, a=11, c=5$

$b=13, a=17. c=11$

$b=19, a=23, c=17$

$b=43, a=47, c=41$

---

$a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc=28$

$b^2+(b+4)^2+(b-2)^2-b(b+4)-(b+4)(b-2)-b(b-2)=28$

$b^2+b^2+8b+16+b^2-4b+4-b^2-4b-b^2+2b-4b+8-b^2+2b=28$

$8b+16-4b+4-4b+2b-4b+8+2b=28$

$28=28$ regardless of $b$.

So select $b$ prime where $(b+4)$ and $(b-2)$ are prime. Open question how many such there are.

Comment: What about the examples $$f(613,617,619)=28\\f(641,643,647)=28$$ and we can find other larger. (I don't discard I am misunderstanding your reasoning (I am in a hurry at this moment).

Comment: I think there are places where those would be accounted for were I to have used absolute values instead. $x^2+y^2+(x+y)^2=56$ has solutions for negative values of $x$ and $y$ which in turn imply values for $a,b,c$. I just found a subset of the solutions. I think including negative values would give you another subset. Nobody knows, but my guess is both subsets have infinitely many elements.